# Value of WEBEDIT object during recording, is not stored in OR in QTP

Tags: qtp

I want to know how to store value entered in a webedit box duting recording, in object repository. I entered value 'XY' in google search box. It showed up as

Code:

```
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("q").Set "XY"
```

However, in OR property "value" is blank.

On other hand, if I manually add this WebEdit object means Google Search box using ' 'add object to local' button then `GetTOproperty` gives me value as XY (though `getROProperty` still gives property "value" as blank)

Please tell me why value entered in webedit box during recording doesn't get stored in OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the value of an edit field to the description of the edit field would usually be a very bad idea. It would mean that changing the value of the object will cause its description to change so you would have to have multiple test objects depending on the *previous* value of the object.

If you really do want to use the *value* as part of the description add it in the object identification dialog (**Tools → Object Identificaiton**).

You should also read up on the differences between [`GetROProperty` and `GetTOProperty`](http://qtp.blogspot.co.il/2008/05/qtp-gettoproperties-getroproperty.html).

Comment: Hi,  Thanks so much for clarifying it for me. Just one small question is, after adding "value" property from Object Identification if I use GetROProperty & do following,

MsgBox Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("q").GetROProperty("value")

it gives me msgbox with blank value since yes at run time am not entering any value in WebEdit box. So, how can I enter any value in WebEditbox(google search box) at run time & then see it using GetROProperty. Really thanks for your help :)

Comment: `WebEdit("q").Set "XX"`

Comment: Thanks Again for explaining it so well ! Understood it. When I ran test to get value of editbox at runtime after your hint, I got expected output but it gave two warnings in test result.These were that "Object was not found" If you could again help me with that.